# How to define start value for ID column in SQLAlchemy for SQLServer?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pymssql

I interfacing SQLAlchemy between Flask and SQLServer.

I have an ID column which I would like to start from 10000. I couldn't find the answer.

Below is the SQL code, I am trying to convert to SQLAlchemy.

Please let me know.

Thx

```
create TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(**10000**,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Brand] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [Price] [real] NOT NULL,
    [Qty] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductFilenamePrefix] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Name] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting SQLAlchemy autoincrement start value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494033/setting-sqlalchemy-autoincrement-start-value)

Comment: I think this is an duplicate question of this: [Setting SQLAlchemy autoincrement start value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494033/setting-sqlalchemy-autoincrement-start-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do some changes after SQLAlchemy creates the table, as shown in the links above for MySQL, but with SQL Server.

```
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy import DDL
event.listen(
    Article.__table__,
    "after_create",
    DDL("DBCC checkident (%(table)s, reseed, 9999)")
)
```

This will make the next record inserted start at an identity value of 10000. Good luck.

Comment: If this works, could you mark it as correct? Thanks!

Comment: I wish.. I just don't have enough reputation. I am 8 so far.

Comment: I think you should be able to mark correct, even if you can't vote yet, but I may be wrong. The check mark rather than the up arrow.