# How to start SQLAlchemy primary_key at a given number?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a simple SQLAlchemy model, with a column for the ID:

```
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

This will start the `id` at 0, and autoincrement by 1. How do I make it start at `1000` instead of `0`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting SQLAlchemy autoincrement start value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494033/setting-sqlalchemy-autoincrement-start-value)

Comment: @shmee no, that's for setting the *autoincrement* value, not the start value.

Comment: The solution you just accepted, using SQLA's [Sequence](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Sequence) object is exactly what is outlined in Edwardr's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10495449/4134674) in the linked Q&A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import Sequence

id = Column(Integer, Sequence('id_sequence', start=1000, increment=1), primary_key=True)
```