# How to Start Primary key with a particular number in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I have a Sqlite Database and created a model using Sqlalchemy with below code :

```
class Patient(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'patient'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, Sequence('pat_id_seq',start=123450001,increment=1), primary_key=True)
    ssn_id = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

I want the `id` to start with `123450001`, but it always starts with `"1"`, is there a possible way to do this ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494033/setting-sqlalchemy-autoincrement-start-value/10495449) answer your question?

Comment: i tried that, it says integer takes no argument and i included sequence in my code which is not working.