# After deleting a row in SQLite, _ID of a new entry is not consecutive

Tags: android, sqlite

I use this method to delete a row in my sqlite db:

```
db.execSQL("delete from "+TABLE_NUMS+" where _ID = '" + this.rowID + "'");
```

and then I update the rest of Ids to make my entries consecutive:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE "+TABLE_NUMS+" set _ID = (_ID - 1) WHERE _ID > "+this.rowID);
```

And it works fine, but when I add new entries to my DB, the ID of the new entries still add as if the deleted entries existed, say I have 10 rows with IDs starting from 1 to 10, and then I delete number 5 and 6, the rows become 1 to 8, but the new entry's ID will be 11. So my IDs sequence would be 1 to 8 and 11. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you need consecutive numbers? You should live with this behavior, this is how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite keeps track of the largest ROWID that a table has ever held using the special SQLITE_SEQUENCE table. You cam modify that sequence as:

```
UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = this.ID -1 WHERE name = TABLE_NUMS
```

The same functionality is asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692856/set-start-value-for-autoincrement-in-sqlite).

Comment: There should be no need to mess with the sequence / autoincrement, please take care with advice like this!

Comment: @Nanne is right, you have to change your logic, modifying the autoincrement is not a good idea.

Comment: Thank u guys for all the info. I'd better off with changing the logic then.

Answer (score 3):

> The normal ROWID selection algorithm described above will generate
>   monotonically increasing unique ROWIDs as long as you never use the
>   maximum ROWID value and you never delete the entry in the table with
>   the largest ROWID. If you ever delete rows or if you ever create a row
>   with the maximum possible ROWID, then ROWIDs from previously deleted
>   rows might be reused when creating new rows and newly created ROWIDs
>   might not be in strictly ascending order.
>   http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

This is how SQLite works.

If you really need to have the Ids consecutive don't use autoincrement.
Insert the ids yourself.
You can select MAX(_ID) first to get the last id (greatest value).

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have autoincrement set on _ID when you created the table. So, every row you add will be given a number automatically unless you explicitly set it. If it is absolutely necessary that you need the _IDs in consecutive order, I recommend that you set it yourself instead of using autoincrement.

Here is how to reset it:

```
delete from your_table;    
delete from sqlite_sequence where name='your_table';
```

This will delete all your data and reset the sequence.

Comment: There should be no real need for this in most cases, so unless there is a really definate reason, I would NOT recommend setting the id manually, ever. I just don't see the need.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite keeps the largest ROWID in the special SQLITE_SEQUENCE table. You can update that table as:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 0 WHERE NAME = '"+TABLE_NAME+"'");
```

OR

delete that table as:

```
db.delete("SQLITE_SEQUENCE","NAME = ?",new String[]{TABLE_NAME});
```