# Is it possible to insert a row with a given id in a table where the id field is autoincremented?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have tried it on android and it seems that simply ignores the given value assigned to the id field and just assigns it an autoincremented value (default behaviour).

Is there anyway to do this? I wanna do something like insert into table(id,name) values (100,"my name"). And let sqlite insert a row with id=100 not id=1 when the table is empty.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692856/set-start-value-for-autoincrement-in-sqlite/692871#692871

Comment: That works for me. You can set the id manually but it will increment the index counter to at least that id. So data inserted afterwards without explicit id will start at 101 for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify a value for a column, that value is used. (See the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).)

And for me, it works:

```
> CREATE TABLE t(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
> INSERT INTO t VALUES(NULL);
> INSERT INTO t VALUES(123);
> INSERT INTO t VALUES(NULL);
> SELECT * FROM t;
1
123
124
```

Comment: thanks for that. Don't know why it did not work previously :/.