# how to modify start of auto_increment of primary key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite

I am making an invoice app for my company and want to start my invoices where my old system left( 909). How can I go about this? I thought that modifying the invoices table' primary key to start auto increment at 909. How would you guys go about this? I am using rails 4 and sqlite for db.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set start value for AUTOINCREMENT in SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692856/set-start-value-for-autoincrement-in-sqlite)

Comment: The answer suggested is not explicit on how to do this. Please help out a rookie. Iv'e searched throughly and cannot find an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your invoices table is called `invoices`, run the following SQL query:

```
UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 909 WHERE name = 'invoices'
```

You can set the initial value in a migration right after creating the table.  In your migration use:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 909 WHERE name = 'invoices'")
```

Comment: Infused thanks for your answer. Could you please walk me through? Is this to be done through rails console? ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can either run it via `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` or directly through the `sqlite3` console.

Comment: So just run sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3 to enter Sql console right? I lve had trouble through irb.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Then you should just be able to paste in the SQL followed by a semi-colon.