# Enforce sequential rowids in SQLite tables

Tags: sqlite

Is there a way to have SQLite force rowids to be sequential and start from 0? E.g. if I have this table:

```
    CREATE TABLE memory_by_cpu (
        cpu INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        memory INTEGER NOT NULL
    )
```

I want to ensure that the `cpu` column (which will be equal to the rowid) is sequential and starting at 0.

This is unrelated to `AUTOINCREMENT`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set start value for AUTOINCREMENT in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692856/set-start-value-for-autoincrement-in-sqlite)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35043256/sqlite-starting-rowid-of-0

Comment: No, this is unrelated to `AUTOINCREMENT` which does not enforce anything, it just sets a default value on `INSERT` if you don't supply one.

Comment: You want DB to throw an error if an insert is not sequential?

Comment: @Timmmm take some time and read this: https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: @m0skit0: Exactly

Comment: @formpas: I have. It is not relevant.

Comment: SQLite does not support that. You would need to check manually before the insertion. It would be interesting to know why you want this behavior.

Comment: Same reason any constraints exist: because my data should alway fit this pattern, and it simplifies my code if I can have SQLite enforce the condition rather than having to retrieve the data and manually check it myself.