# Creating an unique database column with auto-increment from a starting number in Rails 4.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

i have a database table with this column `t.integer :account_number, :limit => 9`. I need this column to automatic generate on the account creation, to auto-increment by 50 for each account created and it has to start( from the first account) at value of `450230000`. So i will have the account with `ID = 1` and `ACCOUNT_NUMBER = 450230000`, account with `ID = 2` and `ACCOUNT_NUMBER = 450230050`.
I'm using Rails 4.2.5 and SQLite as database. There is a way to have this type of auto-increment column in Rails?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692856/set-start-value-for-autoincrement-in-sqlite) seems relevant

Comment: Right, i just have to create the first row on my own then delete it when the count will start, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add callback in model before saving your object

```
before_create :set_account_number
def set_account_number
  last_account_number = Account.maximum(:account_number)
  self.account_number = last_account_number.to_i + 50
end
```

Do something like that in your model

Comment: Ok, it works but i need that, by default, on the first account i will create the account number has to be 450230000. It is possible?

Comment: It's is better logic...Nice @M Kumar

Answer (score 1):

This logic, can help you

```
before_create :inc_acc_num   //callback 

def inc_acc_num
  self.account_number = Account.last.try(:account_number) + 50
end
```