# SQLite3: Python Input to Table - Trouble with Auto Increment

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I am currently having an issue with importing data to a sqlite3 table.
In my TEST program, users input their *fake* information when asked for an input.
I then take that input and put it in my Table, however, I am having an issue with the AutoIncrementing "User ID". Each user gets their own ID, and so far there are 5 users. When a new User inputs their data, how do I make it so it automatically sets "UserID" to the next number, in this case 6.

Everything works if I manually put "6" in the first Value (in the following code), but how do I make that automatic?

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('xxxxxxx.db')
c=conn.cursor()
NameCreate = input("Please enter your First and Last name: ")
UserNameCreate = input("Please enter your desired User Name: ")
PasswordCreate = input("Please enter your desired Password: ")
DOBCreate = input("Please enter your date of birth [DD.MM.YYYY]: ")
FavouriteArtistCreate = input("Please enter your favourite Arist: ")
FavouriteGenreCreate = input("Please enter your favourite Genre: ")

c.execute("INSERT INTO Users VALUES (AUTOINCREMENT, '{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}')".format(NameCreate, DOBCreate, UserNameCreate, PasswordCreate, FavouriteArtistCreate, FavouriteGenreCreate))
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to the question itself, not all of your code, and not in an external link.

Comment: 1) What `CREATE TABLE` statement was used to define `Users`? 2) Don't build SQL like this. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Meanwhile, the usual way to do this is to define the column as `AUTOINCREMENT` in the `CREATE TABLE` column-constraint. Have you done that? If not, why not? If so, in what way is it not working as expected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set start value for AUTOINCREMENT in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692856/set-start-value-for-autoincrement-in-sqlite)

Comment: @roganjosh Although I think if he knows he wants "Auto Increment" and couldn't figure out how to set the column `AUTOINCREMENT`, there's a good chance you're right that he also didn't set it `PRIMARY KEY`…

Answer (score 3):

It's not enough to show your operations on the database. You need to show your database schema.

We start with two pieces of warning from sqlite doc:

1. The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.
2. In SQLite, a column with type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is an alias for the ROWID (except in WITHOUT ROWID tables) which is always a 64-bit signed integer.

With that out of the way, the problem with your code is that autoincrement is specified at table creation time, not insertion time.

See a minimal example:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT)")

NameCreate = 'a'
c.execute("INSERT INTO users ('name') VALUES (?)", (NameCreate, ))
conn.commit()
print(c.execute('select * from users').fetchall())
NameCreate = 'b'
c.execute("INSERT INTO users ('name') VALUES (?)", (NameCreate, ))
conn.commit()
print(c.execute('select * from users').fetchall())
```

note the CREATE TABLE line with AUTOINCREMENT, although it's not necessary as sqlite3 will do AUTOINCREMENT on any INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.
So you will need to migrate your database to a new schema with that in your table.

A bad manual solution without migration can go as follows (only for stopgap!), in the above example:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO users ('id', 'name') VALUES ((SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM users), ?)", (NameCreate, ))
```

Comment: Right, the error I am having when I do that is "There is 7 Columns but 1 Value Supplied" - This is because one of the Columns is "User ID", which I want to Auto-Increment, without any User Input.

Comment: So two ways to fix: either list all column names except user ID in your insert, or don't have the Id column at all when you create the table. In sqlite if you don't have a integer primary key you have a hidden column called "rowid" you can query with.

Comment: I faced the same problem reported by @JamesSmith: I was sending a list of parameters without the AUTOINCREMENT-ed key, and SQLite complained about 8 columns in VALUE in a table with 9 columns. The solution was not to mention the primary key in the column list.